# Esri iOS SDK application size

Tags: ios, cocoapods, esri

I'm developing simple app with esri ios sdk. I set up esri-sdk for ios with cocoapods. But cocoapods install all frameworks in project. In xcode estimated project size is about 250 mb. I'm curious when i run ipa file, how much megabyte ipa file will be on device. And then How can i decrese app size

Thanks.